# How do you read a .txt file with stdin .cc file and output it to your shell? pt.2

Tags: linux, emacs, c++

```
//include file from a large library that gives us the ability to program in
//C++
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//
int main()
{
  File * fPointer;

  //fpointer gives direction to which file needs to be opened this case mytxt
  fPointer = fopen("mytext.txt","r");

  char singleLine[150];

  //feof = file end of file
  //means keep looping till end
  while(!feof(fPointer)) {

    //going to go line by line
    //
    fgets(singleLine, 150, fPointer);
   
  }

  //close the pointer or the use of this function
  fclose(fPointer);

  return(0);
}
```

I saw a program somewhere and I modified it a bit to fit my needs and my goal is to turn it into .exe and then have it display what the file mytext.txt has in it (it is 5 lines of content). Have been working on this for hours but still haven't found the issue with it. Please help I am doodoo at this.

[I work with mobaxterm with the unix linux shell (bash files I believe)]

Thank you and stay safe during covid times

Comment: yes, but I still have some issues with the file I made

Comment: Then you post a new, more specific, question. Also, first resort is to use the excellent man pages and compare your calls word-for-word with the prototypes of the functions you are using (exact words and also data types). Better still, use the man page as you code, and copy/paste the calls, then insert your own variable names. Note: you are writing C, whatever the file extension and the comments say about C++.